# Correctly stop FFMPeg from contiuous operation

Tags: c#, ffmpeg

I want to use FFMPeg / alsa to record audio from a microphone. I use this call:

```
ffmpeg -f alsa -i default:CARD=U0x46d0x809 out.wav
```

I call this as an external process from my program. When the user presses a key I want to stop the recording. This is the way it is implemented:

```
string ffmpegParams=$"-f alsa -i default:{carname} {outputfilename";
Process ffmpeg = new Process();
ffmpeg.StartInfo.FileName   = "ffmpeg";
ffmpeg.StartInfo.Arguments =ffmpegParams;
ffmpeg.Start();
// do stuff until keypressed
ffmpeg.Kill();
```

Now I wonder if it is a "good" way to simply kill the process to stop FFMpeg. It feels like the outcome could be unpredictable.

Is there a better way or is this just fine?

Comment: maybe, send `q` to ffmpeg?

Comment: ALSA isn't for Windows, but your `ffmpeg.StartInfo.FileName` shows `ffmpeg.exe`. What is your OS?

Comment: @Ilogan You are right. I am testing/developing on win but the application will/should run on Linux.Mixed up those variants. Corrected the code now